# if $w$ is a normal distribution where $n(0,1)$, then find the mgf of $w^2$.

Tags: calculus, statistics

if $w$ is a normal distribution where $n(0,1)$, then find the mgf of $w^2$. I have looked it up and the answer is chi squared but i cannot seem to find a way to integrate this correctly.

I start the problem by generalizing it as 
$e^{(tx)}* f(x^2)= e^{(tx)}*[1/\sqrt{2\pi } * e^{-(x^2/2)}]^2$

Am I starting this problem of incorrectly ?

Answer (score 1):

Let  $Z$ be standard normal. Then the mgf (moment generating function) of $Z^2$ is $E(tZ^2)$, which is 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tz^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz,$$
which is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(z^2/2-tz^2)}\,dz.$$
To recognize the value of the integral, for suitable $t$ let $z\sqrt{1/2-t}=u/\sqrt{2}$.

**Remark:** Alternately, one can find the density function of $Z^2$, and then use this to find the mgf.